# What's the difference between \mspace and \hspace in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

I know that `amsmath` package provides extra math spacing commands, like the followings  `\,` for `\thinspace`, `\:` for `\medspace` and `\;` for `\thickspace`, there are corresponding negative space as well like `\negthinspace`, `\negmedspace` and `\negthickspace`. But from the package documentation, it says:

> For the greatest possible control over math spacing, use \mspace and ‘math
>   units’.

Besides I tested out that anywhere the `\mspace` command takes effect then the `\hspace` command takes effect as well. I was wondering what's the difference between these two commands when used in math mode? If there's no difference between them why would I bother using `\mspace` as `\hspace` is more often used.

Any hints or help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once having made clear that

1. `\mspace` can only be used in math mode (and requires `amsmath`),
2. `\mspace` only accepts a length expressed in `mu` units (but the `plus` and `minus` components also accept `fil[ll]` units) or in terms of a `mu` based parameter (`\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`),
3. `\hspace` doesn't accept `mu` units,

we can describe the differences.

Both commands insert space that will not interfere with the automatic spacing between atoms. However,

- the value of the `mu` unit for `\mspace` depend on the current math style;
- the value of the `em` or `ex` unit for `\hspace` depends on the text font current at the time the formula began.

In particular, given that 18mu corresponds to the value of 1em in the symbol font (math group 2), the following two formulas will give quite different result

```
$\scriptscriptstyle a\mspace{18mu}b$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\hspace{1em}b$
```

[image]

This is because the former uses the em in `\scriptscriptfont2` (default for 10pt size is `cmsy5`) whereas the latter uses the em in the standard text font (default `cmr10`).

Comment: Thank you! I think I got your idea, they're font dependent commands, and they both work in math mode.

Comment: @Jiapan yes but use hspace and em units is a font dependent command that depends on a font that is unrelated to the math, so it is almost always the wrong command to use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so it's better to use \mspace when in math environment. Gotcha, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what is meant by

> I tested out that anywhere the `\mspace` command takes effect then the
>   `\hspace` command takes effect as well

The `\mspace` is but a thin wrapper for use of TeX's `\mskip` which expects a `<muglue>` specification, i.e. something with `mu` unit which makes sense in math mode.

The `\mspace` macro can be used *only* in math mode.

The `\hspace` macro does *not* accept `mu` unit.

Comment: thanks! I mean `\mspace` and `\hspace` both works in my projects.